# Permission needed for Named pipes on Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions, wcf, named-pipes, ipc

Are there any special permissions needed for domain service account running a windows service which receives messages over named pipes? Hosting environment is Windows Server 2008.

Background:

We have two processes communicating over named pipes. Our windows service exposes WCF service over named pipes binding and a IIS worker process running on the same machine calls that WCF service.

Everything works on our development machines and test server but when we deploy the soution to integration environment the client (IIS worker) is not able to call the service with exception that there is no endpoint listening on the address. The service is up and running and based on logs the service host is listening.

The server is controlled by group policy and low priviledges accounts are used so I think it can be some problem of insufficient permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noticed it the solution is in my question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041805/how-to-add-a-privilege-to-an-account-in-windows